# Exchange 2010 - Running out of space - NOT logs NO whitespace

Tags: exchange-2010

I have a database measuring over 600GB in size.  The individual users total 72GB in size using the following command:

> Get-MailboxStatistics -Database "Corporate" | Sort -Property
>   TotalItemsize | Format-Table DisplayName, LastLoggedOnUserAccount,
>   ItemCount,
>   @{expression={$_.totalitemsize.value.ToMB()};label="Size(MB)"},
>   LastLogonTime, LastLogoffTime

The white space is a total of 15GB.  There are no logs - cleaned up with circular logging.  I have cleaned up recoverable items as well.

That leaves me with over 500GB consumed and I have no idea where from.

I do know that there are dozens upon dozens of automated emails created without going through any sort of email software so I wonder if those emails are eating space, but I have no idea how to see them.

Comment: Have you tried just creating a new mailbox store and moving all the users to it?